# Discord.py | Bot responses when it is pinged

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

If I do something like `if message.content.startswith('hello'):` it works fine.

However, I can't find a way to make it work for pings. I tried bot ID and name. My code with bot ID:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)
    if message.content.startswith('<@741352621826375781>'):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            colour = discord.Colour.red())
     
        embed.add_field(name='Hello', value='''My prefix is `.`, type `.help` for help.''', inline=False)
            
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easier way to check if the bot was mentioned in a message or not.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if client.user in message.mentions:
        await message.channel.send("Hello!")
```

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your issue, The reason your code didn't work is because of an attribute error.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
   if str(message.content) == '<@741352621826375781>':
        await message.channel.send('Hello ?')
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit improved version of Sofia

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message): 
    # Adding `<!@{id_here}>` so it's gonna work whether it's mentioned by nick or simply by the name
    if message.content in [f'<!@{client.user.id}>', f'<@{client.user.id}>']:
        await message.channel.send('Hello there')

    await client.process_commands(message)
```